# SELECT from multiple tables (big data)

Tags: mysql, union, large-data

I have four table with the same structure (id, var1, var2)

Table 1 in var1 have only one word (150000+ records)

Table 2 in var1 have two words (50000+ records)

Table 3 in var1 have three words (50000+ records)

Table 4 in var1 have four or more words (30000+ records)

What is the best way to search them?

I do search as following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE var1 LIKE '".$searchWord."' ORDER BY var1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE var1 LIKE '".$searchWord." %' OR var1 LIKE '% ".$searchWord." %' OR var1 LIKE '% ".$searchWord."' ORDER BY var1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE var1 LIKE '".$searchWord." %' OR var1 LIKE '% ".$searchWord." %' OR var1 LIKE '% ".$searchWord."' ORDER BY var1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table4 WHERE var1 LIKE '".$searchWord." %' OR var1 LIKE '% ".$searchWord." %' OR var1 LIKE '% ".$searchWord."' ORDER BY var1)
) AS WHOLEDATABASE ORDER BY var1
");
```

I do this becouse first I want to show the results with one word, then two, then three, and others.

Is there any other way to do this becouse this way is very slow.

Comment: Hi ikrajinovic, welcome to SO! Why don't you just have a single table with a column to indicate the number of words in `var1` (if that's necessary for your application)? For fast searching like this, read up on [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html). Also, your code may be vulnerable to SQL injection.  You **really** should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your suggestion to add extra column is great.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine result and then sort using length(var1),Union is little cumbersome

Comment: How you meen to combine result. Get them all into array and then sort array or...??

Comment: Also what if one word is longer than 3 words?

Comment: add condition in your query if you want to omit that like length(var1)<4

Comment: I made dictionary. I for better looking I want to displey result as I said.

Comment: @ikrajinovic You better go with eggyal's comment.

Comment: @Fewtron I can't do `like lenght(var1)<4` because I need to count words not caracter.

Comment: use can use little trick to do that :  SUM( LENGTH(col_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col_name, ' ', ''))+1)       in place of count.this give u word ,now u can try your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using concat? If all the search and order fields are indexed, I think concat wouldn't take any extra time.

example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2, table3, table4 
WHERE concat_ws(' ',table1.var1, table2.var1, table3.var1, table4.var1) like '%"'.$searchWord.'"%' 
ORDER BY table1.id, table2.id, table3.id, table4.id;
```

Only problem with this query is, it'll change the output structure of the table.

Comment: No, I didn't try to use concat. I will try today. But I can make order by var1 instead of id.